# Adding structure name in C function prototype, before the return datatype

Tags: c

Going through an open source C code, I came across a header file containing a code which looks like;

```
typedef struct MY_STRUCT {
    //structure members
    //...
} my_struct_t;

MY_STRUCT int funcA();
MY_STRUCT int funcB();
```

My questions is: what is the purpose of adding `MY_STRUCT` in front of the function prototypes?

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
It turned out that `MY_STRUCT` in the function prototype is relates to a macro for a compiler related extension.
I found the following macros.

```
#define DUMMY __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) 
#define MY_STRUCT DUMMY
```

But, can I now consider it bad coding to use `MY_STRUCT` as the structure's name? Or does this look intentional?

Comment: can you post the URL for this open source code?

Comment: This is not legal C, unless MY_STRUCT is `#define`d elsewhere.

Comment: MY_STRUCT might be used for a macro. Example might be to use compiler specific extension about calling convention, packing, inlining, optimization

Comment: This is giving a syntax error for me. There might be some preprocessor black magic going on here, as suggested by @n.m.

Comment: This is not a complete example and there is no way we can be sure. In particular, you have not actually provided the definition of `MY_STRUCT`. You have provided a definition of `struct MY_STRUCT` but that is not the same as just `MY_STRUCT`.

Comment: @josina well it seems you have found the answer. And yes in IMO it is bad style, but on the other hand there may be a reason why they did this, and without seeing the whole picture we cannot be sure.

Comment: As this involves compiler specifics you should probably include the compiler among the tags. I also suspect that this is (potential) C++, have you checked this? If it's C++ please update the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses compiler specific extensions, probably GCC. The purpose of this is to set the visibility for `my_struct_t`, `FuncA` and `FuncB`. According to GCC documentation on visibility:

> Default visibility is the normal case for the object file
>             format.  This value is available for the visibility attribute
>             to override other options that may change the assumed
>             visibility of entities.
>
> On ELF, default visibility means that the declaration is
>             visible to other modules and, in shared libraries, means that
>             the declared entity may be overridden.
>
> On Darwin, default visibility means that the declaration is
>             visible to other modules.
>
> Default visibility corresponds to "external linkage" in the
>             language.

This of course suggest that the code is compiled with flags (for example `-fvisibility=hidden`) that doesn't put symbols in `default` visibility by default which is normal when for example compiling dynamic libraries. Basically `default` visibility means that the symbol should be externally visible in the dynamic library.

Note also that by setting the visibility on a type they are using constructs that are only allowed/meaningful in C++ mode.

The question on whether this is bad or good practice is a matter of opinion. It's quite normally accepted that one only puts enable external visibility on functions that are part of the API of the dynamic library and for various reason it's common to use macro for that (part because different compilers differ, but also because you want to declare them differently when then using the library).

However using the macro name `MY_STRUCT` is IMHO confusing and obviously it confused you and others too. One would not expect `MY_STRUCT` to be the "magic symbol" that makes a symbol externally visible. I'd suggest calling it `MYLIB_API` or something similar.